# Rialto starting player and initial order on Doge track

Tags: turn-order, rialto

I have a Czech localisation of Rialto, and I am confused about the initial order on the Doge track. Assume a game of 3 players, with Blue the starting player, followed by Red and then Yellow.

Reading the rules of "Preparing the game, point 11", I see:

> Beginning with the starting player, place one of your marker tokens on the starting square of the Doge track."

(Translation mine)

Thew way I understand this, the Blue player will place his marker first, then Red on top of him, and then Yellow on top of them both. So the starting player will be last on the Doge track, and the last player will be leading the Doge track.

However, this feels wrong, since that way, the starting player is penalised in everything:

- According to point 14, the starting player gets the smallest number of coins: the starting player takes coins first, and number of coins taken by successive players increases.
- According to point 15, the starting player is the last to choose a building, and so has the least choice: the order of choice is specified to start with the player to the right of the starting player, and proceed counter-clockwise.
- Once play starts, cards are chosen according to the order on the Doge track, so the starting player is last again and has the least choice.

To add to my confusion, the illustration demonstrating an initial setup has the Blue player holding 1 coin and being the *topmost* marker on the Doge track.

What are the rules actually supposed to say? Is this a mistranslation of the Czech localisation, or is the starting player really the worst position to be in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a copy of the English rules, and point 11 reads of the setup reads as follows:

> Beginning with the player to the right of the starting player and in counter-clockwise order, each player puts one counter on the first space of the **Doge track**.
> *See below for details on the Doge track.*

This would produce the opposite order of yours.

BoardGameGeek has a [file](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/133163/official-czech-rules-corrections) titled "Official Czech Rules with corrections." Step 11 of that document reads as follows:

> Postupně od hráče po pravici začínajícího hráče a dále
>   proti směru hodinových ručiček umístěte své označovací kameny
>   na počáteční pole **stupnice vlivu dóžete** *(více o stupnici vlivu dóžete
>   najdete níže na této straně)*.

The quoted passage is in red, which has been used to identify the corrections.

This matches the the text of the English rules I quoted above.

Comment: Wow, that correction precisely addresses my question. I browsed BoardGameGeek forums before asking this, but as I am not familiar with that site, I didn't know there could be files for download.